# How to shift the columns of table from CSV?

Tags: python, csv

I've added new headings(parameters) for the CSV data and the new parameter's have to be calculated so it needs to stay empty. I need to shift the whole data to the right by one column and I can't figure out how with python v 3.2
Can anybody please help me?

So when I open my python CSV file with excel, it gives me something like this(super simplified version, I have thousands of rows and columns)

```
P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 ...

1  2  3  4  5
1  2  3  4  5
1  2  3  4  5
```

.
.

And I want to change this to; leaving P1 empty.

```
P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 ...

    1  2  3  4  
    1  2  3  4   
    1  2  3  4
```

This is the code that I've got so far. I just want to shift that data to the right by one column. Can anybody please help me?
Thanks in advance!

```
    import csv

    # reads the input and spits out the output
    with open ('DownloadDB_CSV1.csv', 'r') as csvinput:
         with open ('outputCSV.csv', 'w', newline ='') as csvoutput:
             reader = csv.reader(csvinput, delimiter = ',')
            writer = csv.writer(csvoutput,  delimiter = ',')
    all = []
    row = next(reader)
    row.insert(0,'GenomePosition')
    all.append(row)



    for row in reader:
        all.append(row)
        contents = row[0::] # sepearte it to a variable
    writer.writerows(all)
```

Comment: How? You mean in excel? I need to shift those in python script not in excel.

Comment: ok, you are taking correct array, but still you write it from begining. so my question is: what is empty collumn in exel? why you not writting it?

Comment: I'm new to the python and Ive been doing all the matrix manipulations through matlab,,, so I can't think of any ways to move those data to next column,,,,,

Comment: What do you want I the new column, an empty string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you need to do, to insert an empty column, is to add to each line an initial `,`. Here's some code to do that - you don't even need the CSV module to do it. From your example, I suppose you don't want to shift the headers, right?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
#  test_csv.py
#  
#  Copyright 2015 John Coppens <john@jcoppens.com>
#  
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
#  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#  
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#  
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
#  Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston,
#  MA 02110-1301, USA.
#  
#  

SEPARATOR = ","

def add_empty(infile, outfile):
    with open(outfile, "w") as outf:
        with open(infile, "r") as inf:
            line = inf.readline()       # Copy the header
            outf.write(line)

            while True:
                line = inf.readline()
                if line == "": break    # EOF
                outf.write("" + SEPARATOR + line)

def main():
    add_empty("test.csv", "testshifted.csv")
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```